# PHP Get keys from one array of intersected values

Tags: php, arrays

in php, if I have two arrays:

```
array1 = array('a', 'b', 'c');
array2 = array('b', 'c');
```

Is there a function of combination of functions that will compare the two arrays' values and return the keys from 1 array of the intersection?

If wanting the `key`s from `array1`, they would be `1` and `2`
If wanting the `key`s from `array2`, they would be `0` and `1`

Comment: I think you meant the keys from array1 would be 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare:

```
$rgResult = array_keys(array_intersect($array1, $array2));
```

and

```
$rgResult = array_keys(array_intersect($array2, $array1));
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `array_intersect`

```
array_keys(array_intersect($array1, $array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_keys($array1 = array('a', 'b', 'c'); $array2 = array('b', 'c');

$intersection = array_intersect($array1, $array2);

$keys = array();
foreach($intersection as $i){
    $keys[]= array_search($i,$array1);
}
print_r($keys);
```